# How to find all occurrences of a non - contiguous substring in Python?

Tags: python, string, bioinformatics, combinatorics, biopython

**Premise:**

I am currently working on the following problem:

> http://rosalind.info/problems/sseq/

I must find the index combinations of all occurrences of a substring in a string, where the substring is not necessarily contiguous.

My testing parameters:

```
Main_String = ACGGTTAACGTGACGGTTAAGSSGSSTSSTSSASSA
Substring = GGTTAA
```

Non-contiguous means that an occurrence of the `Substring` in the `Main_String` may look like this:
`GGSTTSAASSS` where the substring is `GGTTAA` and the MAIN_STRING - `GGSTTSAASSS`.

The substring, although cut by random characters (S in our case) is still to be found in the main string. As such, a possible answer would be `(format:Letter((index + 1) in Main_String)) G(1)G(2)T(4)T(5)A(7)A(8) = 1, 2, 4, 5, 7, 8.` That is easy enough to get for the first match. I need to get all possible variations though, so if we use my testing parameters from above, correct answers would be:

`3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8 and 3, 12, 17, 18, 19, 20 and 3, 15, 17, 18, 19, 20 and so on up to 21, 24, 27, 30, 33, 36`.

**Question:**

I need an algorithm that can provide me with all possible variations of a non-contiguous substring in a given string.

**Issue:**

This is the code I have so far, which works to an extent, but does not return all possible variations, only some of them.

```
    dna = ''
counter = -1
dna_subseq = ''
dna_subseq_indexes = []


with open('Rosalind_dna.txt', 'r') as file:
    data = file.read().split('\n')
    for line in data:
        if line == '':
            continue
        if 'Rosalind' in line and counter < 1:
            counter += 1
            continue
        elif 'Rosalind' not in line and counter < 1:
            dna += line
        elif 'Rosalind' not in line and counter >= 1:
            dna_subseq += line

result = 0
dna_subseq_minus_start = dna_subseq[1:]


def find_next(start_parameter, base):
    result_func = dna.find(base, start_parameter)
    if result_func + 1 in dna_subseq_indexes_subcombo:
        if result_func + 1 == 0:
            return
        find_next(start_parameter + 1, base)
    else:
        dna_subseq_indexes_subcombo.append(result_func + 1)
        return


for index, value in enumerate(dna):
    global_start = index
    result = 0
    while result != -1:
        dna_subseq_indexes_subcombo = []
        if value == dna_subseq[0]:
            dna_subseq_indexes_subcombo.append(index + 1)
            Flag = True
            for base in dna_subseq_minus_start:
                if Flag:
                    start = global_start
                    Flag = False
                result = dna.find(base, start)
                if result + 1 in dna_subseq_indexes_subcombo:
                    find_next(start + 1, base)
                else:
                    dna_subseq_indexes_subcombo.append(result + 1)
                    start += 1
            dna_subseq_indexes.append(dna_subseq_indexes_subcombo)
            global_start += 1
        else:
            break


final_result = []
for x in dna_subseq_indexes:
    test = x.copy()
    test.sort()
    if test == x:
        final_result.append(x)
    else:
        continue
print(final_result)
```

Comment: Can you point the missing results ?

Comment: 3, 10, 11, 17, 19, 20 - where each Number is the respective Index + 1 of the main_string and probably many more, but that one for sure

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure your algorithm could find all solutions even if it would be fixed. I tried this logic instead :
Find the initial sequence closest to the left of dna and search all declinations going from right to left recursively. This way the solutions are automatically sorted.

```
dna        = 'ACGGTTAACGTGACGGTTAAGSSGSSTSSTSSASSA'
dna_len    = len(dna)
dna_subseq = 'GGTTAA'
subseq_len = len(dna_subseq)
count      = 0
print_mode = True # Prints the solutions, set to False to collect them instead

# Finds a single solution starting from the previous one or from a null solution
def find_one_solution(prev_solution, subseq_start, dna_start):
    global dna, dna_subseq, subseq_len, count, mode
    searched   = dna_subseq[subseq_start]
    coll       = prev_solution[:subseq_start]
    subseq_idx = subseq_start

    for i in range(dna_start, len(dna), 1):
        letter = dna[i]
        if letter == searched:
            coll.append(i)
            subseq_idx += 1
        if (subseq_idx == subseq_len): break
        else: searched = dna_subseq[subseq_idx]
    if len(coll) < subseq_len: return None
    count += 1
    if (print_mode): print(coll)
    return coll

# Recursive function
def find_all_solutions(solutions, solution, subseq_start, limit):
    global dna, dna_subseq, subseq_len, print_mode

    for start in range(subseq_len-1, limit-1, -1):
        # last element
        if start == subseq_len-1:
            while True:
                temp = find_one_solution(solution, start, solution[-1]+1)
                if temp == None: break
                else: solution = temp
                if (not print_mode): solutions.append(solution)
        # other elements
        else:
            # finds the next solution
            temp = find_one_solution(solution, start, solution[start]+1)
            if temp == None:
                continue
            else:
                solution = temp
                if (not print_mode): solutions.append(solution)
                # and restarts from end with subseq_start as the left limit
                find_all_solutions(solutions, solution, subseq_len-1, start)


def main():
    all_solutions       = []
    # Finds the initial solution
    initial_solution    = [0] * subseq_len
    initial_solution    = find_one_solution(initial_solution, 0, initial_solution[0])
    if initial_solution == None:
        print("No solution found")
    else:
        if (not print_mode): all_solutions.append(initial_solution)
        # Finds all other solutions
        find_all_solutions(all_solutions, initial_solution, subseq_len-1, 0)
        if (not print_mode): print(all_solutions)
        print("Total count:", count)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main()


#289 solutions found : [[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 12], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 18], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 19], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 32], [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 35], [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 12], [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 18], [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 19], [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 32], [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 35], [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 18], [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 19], [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 32], [2, 3, 4, 5, 12, 35], [2, 3, 4, 5, 18, 19], [2, 3, 4, 5, 18, 32], [2, 3, 4, 5, 18, 35], [2, 3, 4, 5, 19, 32], [2, 3, 4, 5, 19, 35], [2, 3, 4, 5, 32, 35], [2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 18], [2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 19], [2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 32], [2, 3, 4, 10, 12, 35], [2, 3, 4, 10, 18, 19], [2, 3, 4, 10, 18, 32], [2, 3, 4, 10, 18, 35], [2, 3, 4, 10, 19, 32], [2, 3, 4, 10, 19, 35], [2, 3, 4, 10, 32, 35], [2, 3, 4, 16, 18, 19], [2, 3, 4, 16, 18, 32], [2, 3, 4, 16, 18, 35], [2, 3, 4, 16, 19, 32], [2, 3, 4, 16, 19, 35], [2, 3, 4, 16, 32, 35], [2, 3, 4, 17, 18, 19], [2, 3, 4, 17, 18, 32], [2, 3, 4, 17, 18, 35], [2, 3, 4, 17, 19, 32], [2, 3, 4, 17, 19, 35], [2, 3, 4, 17, 32, 35], [2, 3, 4, 26, 32, 35], [2, 3, 4, 29, 32, 35], [2, 3, 5, 10, 12, 18], [2, 3, 5, 10, 12, 19], [2, 3, 5, 10, 12, 32], [2, 3, 5, 10, 12, 35], [2, 3, 5, 10, 18, 19], [2, 3, 5, 10, 18, 32], [2, 3, 5, 10, 18, 35], [2, 3, 5, 10, 19, 32], [2, 3, 5, 10, 19, 35], [2, 3, 5, 10, 32, 35], [2, 3, 5, 16, 18, 19], [2, 3, 5, 16, 18, 32], [2, 3, 5, 16, 18, 35], [2, 3, 5, 16, 19, 32], [2, 3, 5, 16, 19, 35], [2, 3, 5, 16, 32, 35], [2, 3, 5, 17, 18, 19], [2, 3, 5, 17, 18, 32], [2, 3, 5, 17, 18, 35], [2, 3, 5, 17, 19, 32], [2, 3, 5, 17, 19, 35], [2, 3, 5, 17, 32, 35], [2, 3, 5, 26, 32, 35], [2, 3, 5, 29, 32, 35], [2, 3, 10, 16, 18, 19], [2, 3, 10, 16, 18, 32], [2, 3, 10, 16, 18, 35], [2, 3, 10, 16, 19, 32], [2, 3, 10, 16, 19, 35], [2, 3, 10, 16, 32, 35], [2, 3, 10, 17, 18, 19], [2, 3, 10, 17, 18, 32], [2, 3, 10, 17, 18, 35], [2, 3, 10, 17, 19, 32], [2, 3, 10, 17, 19, 35], [2, 3, 10, 17, 32, 35], [2, 3, 10, 26, 32, 35], [2, 3, 10, 29, 32, 35], [2, 3, 16, 17, 18, 19], [2, 3, 16, 17, 18, 32], [2, 3, 16, 17, 18, 35], [2, 3, 16, 17, 19, 32], [2, 3, 16, 17, 19, 35], [2, 3, 16, 17, 32, 35], [2, 3, 16, 26, 32, 35], [2, 3, 16, 29, 32, 35], [2, 3, 17, 26, 32, 35], [2, 3, 17, 29, 32, 35], [2, 3, 26, 29, 32, 35], [2, 9, 10, 16, 18, 19], [2, 9, 10, 16, 18, 32], [2, 9, 10, 16, 18, 35], [2, 9, 10, 16, 19, 32], [2, 9, 10, 16, 19, 35], [2, 9, 10, 16, 32, 35], [2, 9, 10, 17, 18, 19], [2, 9, 10, 17, 18, 32], [2, 9, 10, 17, 18, 35], [2, 9, 10, 17, 19, 32], [2, 9, 10, 17, 19, 35], [2, 9, 10, 17, 32, 35], [2, 9, 10, 26, 32, 35], [2, 9, 10, 29, 32, 35], [2, 9, 16, 17, 18, 19], [2, 9, 16, 17, 18, 32], [2, 9, 16, 17, 18, 35], [2, 9, 16, 17, 19, 32], [2, 9, 16, 17, 19, 35], [2, 9, 16, 17, 32, 35], [2, 9, 16, 26, 32, 35], [2, 9, 16, 29, 32, 35], [2, 9, 17, 26, 32, 35], [2, 9, 17, 29, 32, 35], [2, 9, 26, 29, 32, 35], [2, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19], [2, 11, 16, 17, 18, 32], [2, 11, 16, 17, 18, 35], [2, 11, 16, 17, 19, 32], [2, 11, 16, 17, 19, 35], [2, 11, 16, 17, 32, 35], [2, 11, 16, 26, 32, 35], [2, 11, 16, 29, 32, 35], [2, 11, 17, 26, 32, 35], [2, 11, 17, 29, 32, 35], [2, 11, 26, 29, 32, 35], [2, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19], [2, 14, 16, 17, 18, 32], [2, 14, 16, 17, 18, 35], [2, 14, 16, 17, 19, 32], [2, 14, 16, 17, 19, 35], [2, 14, 16, 17, 32, 35], [2, 14, 16, 26, 32, 35], [2, 14, 16, 29, 32, 35], [2, 14, 17, 26, 32, 35], [2, 14, 17, 29, 32, 35], [2, 14, 26, 29, 32, 35], [2, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [2, 15, 16, 17, 18, 32], [2, 15, 16, 17, 18, 35], [2, 15, 16, 17, 19, 32], [2, 15, 16, 17, 19, 35], [2, 15, 16, 17, 32, 35], [2, 15, 16, 26, 32, 35], [2, 15, 16, 29, 32, 35], [2, 15, 17, 26, 32, 35], [2, 15, 17, 29, 32, 35], [2, 15, 26, 29, 32, 35], [2, 20, 26, 29, 32, 35], [2, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35], [3, 9, 10, 16, 18, 19], [3, 9, 10, 16, 18, 32], [3, 9, 10, 16, 18, 35], [3, 9, 10, 16, 19, 32], [3, 9, 10, 16, 19, 35], [3, 9, 10, 16, 32, 35], [3, 9, 10, 17, 18, 19], [3, 9, 10, 17, 18, 32], [3, 9, 10, 17, 18, 35], [3, 9, 10, 17, 19, 32], [3, 9, 10, 17, 19, 35], [3, 9, 10, 17, 32, 35], [3, 9, 10, 26, 32, 35], [3, 9, 10, 29, 32, 35], [3, 9, 16, 17, 18, 19], [3, 9, 16, 17, 18, 32], [3, 9, 16, 17, 18, 35], [3, 9, 16, 17, 19, 32], [3, 9, 16, 17, 19, 35], [3, 9, 16, 17, 32, 35], [3, 9, 16, 26, 32, 35], [3, 9, 16, 29, 32, 35], [3, 9, 17, 26, 32, 35], [3, 9, 17, 29, 32, 35], [3, 9, 26, 29, 32, 35], [3, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19], [3, 11, 16, 17, 18, 32], [3, 11, 16, 17, 18, 35], [3, 11, 16, 17, 19, 32], [3, 11, 16, 17, 19, 35], [3, 11, 16, 17, 32, 35], [3, 11, 16, 26, 32, 35], [3, 11, 16, 29, 32, 35], [3, 11, 17, 26, 32, 35], [3, 11, 17, 29, 32, 35], [3, 11, 26, 29, 32, 35], [3, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19], [3, 14, 16, 17, 18, 32], [3, 14, 16, 17, 18, 35], [3, 14, 16, 17, 19, 32], [3, 14, 16, 17, 19, 35], [3, 14, 16, 17, 32, 35], [3, 14, 16, 26, 32, 35], [3, 14, 16, 29, 32, 35], [3, 14, 17, 26, 32, 35], [3, 14, 17, 29, 32, 35], [3, 14, 26, 29, 32, 35], [3, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [3, 15, 16, 17, 18, 32], [3, 15, 16, 17, 18, 35], [3, 15, 16, 17, 19, 32], [3, 15, 16, 17, 19, 35], [3, 15, 16, 17, 32, 35], [3, 15, 16, 26, 32, 35], [3, 15, 16, 29, 32, 35], [3, 15, 17, 26, 32, 35], [3, 15, 17, 29, 32, 35], [3, 15, 26, 29, 32, 35], [3, 20, 26, 29, 32, 35], [3, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35], [9, 11, 16, 17, 18, 19], [9, 11, 16, 17, 18, 32], [9, 11, 16, 17, 18, 35], [9, 11, 16, 17, 19, 32], [9, 11, 16, 17, 19, 35], [9, 11, 16, 17, 32, 35], [9, 11, 16, 26, 32, 35], [9, 11, 16, 29, 32, 35], [9, 11, 17, 26, 32, 35], [9, 11, 17, 29, 32, 35], [9, 11, 26, 29, 32, 35], [9, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19], [9, 14, 16, 17, 18, 32], [9, 14, 16, 17, 18, 35], [9, 14, 16, 17, 19, 32], [9, 14, 16, 17, 19, 35], [9, 14, 16, 17, 32, 35], [9, 14, 16, 26, 32, 35], [9, 14, 16, 29, 32, 35], [9, 14, 17, 26, 32, 35], [9, 14, 17, 29, 32, 35], [9, 14, 26, 29, 32, 35], [9, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [9, 15, 16, 17, 18, 32], [9, 15, 16, 17, 18, 35], [9, 15, 16, 17, 19, 32], [9, 15, 16, 17, 19, 35], [9, 15, 16, 17, 32, 35], [9, 15, 16, 26, 32, 35], [9, 15, 16, 29, 32, 35], [9, 15, 17, 26, 32, 35], [9, 15, 17, 29, 32, 35], [9, 15, 26, 29, 32, 35], [9, 20, 26, 29, 32, 35], [9, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35], [11, 14, 16, 17, 18, 19], [11, 14, 16, 17, 18, 32], [11, 14, 16, 17, 18, 35], [11, 14, 16, 17, 19, 32], [11, 14, 16, 17, 19, 35], [11, 14, 16, 17, 32, 35], [11, 14, 16, 26, 32, 35], [11, 14, 16, 29, 32, 35], [11, 14, 17, 26, 32, 35], [11, 14, 17, 29, 32, 35], [11, 14, 26, 29, 32, 35], [11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 32], [11, 15, 16, 17, 18, 35], [11, 15, 16, 17, 19, 32], [11, 15, 16, 17, 19, 35], [11, 15, 16, 17, 32, 35], [11, 15, 16, 26, 32, 35], [11, 15, 16, 29, 32, 35], [11, 15, 17, 26, 32, 35], [11, 15, 17, 29, 32, 35], [11, 15, 26, 29, 32, 35], [11, 20, 26, 29, 32, 35], [11, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 32], [14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 35], [14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 32], [14, 15, 16, 17, 19, 35], [14, 15, 16, 17, 32, 35], [14, 15, 16, 26, 32, 35], [14, 15, 16, 29, 32, 35], [14, 15, 17, 26, 32, 35], [14, 15, 17, 29, 32, 35], [14, 15, 26, 29, 32, 35], [14, 20, 26, 29, 32, 35], [14, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35], [15, 20, 26, 29, 32, 35], [15, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35], [20, 23, 26, 29, 32, 35]]
```

To test the validity of the algorithm, I used a simpler sequence from which all the solutions are easy to find manually :

```
dna = 'AAAAAAAA'
dna_subseq = 'AAAA'
```

Note that I worked with zero based indices because it's simpler, but you could easily add 1 to all results if you need it.

Comment: Thank you! This is an approach I have never considered before and I find it very interesting! I try to run it with a sample dataset which I will post into a pastebin since it is too big and cannot fit here. Unfortunately I run into memory errors and cannot at this point confirm if the solution is correct, though after reviewing the code and your test example, I believe it is. Im about to tackle the memory error now, but i ll be very happy if you have any tips for how to approach it :) 

The sample dataset i used:
https://pastebin.com/Sy8hdZrq

Comment: I don't think any personal computer will have enough memory to handle the case given in that link, especially in python using lists (I guess it can consume several dozen of gigabytes of memory). A possible solution would be to write the result on a file instead of keeping it in memory. After a test, it appears that `find_one_solution` is able to find individual solutions without any issue. The problem starts when accumulating the solutions in the final container (continue in next comment).

Comment: If instead of pushing each solution in a list `find_all_solutions_from_start` would store it in a file, the memory problem would be fixed (check that the file doesn't become to big however because I have no idea of how many solutions will be found, probably a lot...). After that the other problem could be the time consumed by the whole process. It should be a good idea to implement a kind of progress indicator so you can extrapolate after some minutes or hours if there is any chance that the computation ends before next year :-) Let me know if it works.

Comment: Thank you for the tips! I will research on how to write in a file and how to write a progress indicator and as soon as I implement it in a code, I ll write back, though I suspect i Il probably tackle it next week since I have an exam to deal with now :)

Comment: I came with this idea : simply count the results and print a progress report without collecting anything. Starting with the last index (74), going from right to left, the index 71 was reached after maybe two minutes. Finding the index 70 would take ± an hour. Finding all solutions would take one hour * 75^70 which would take thousand of billions of years... (just find the 5 next indices would take 270 milleniums). So it appears clearly that this problem is not reasonably solvable even if the code would be optimized a lot (1000 times faster would still take several years for 5 indexes).

Comment: Moreover I found an error in my codes : the iterations must always go from right to left. It was the case for outer loop but the recursions went from left to right which resulted in some missing solutions. After fixed that, 2 times more solutions was found for the given dna and subsequence. You'll find the fix in my post and also a way of testing it. (PS : If you're interested in the version testing the long sequence, as explained in my previous comment, let me know : I could put a file you can download somewhere)

Comment: Thank you for the help with my question! Since my question was, without the use of quantum computers, practically unanswerable in our lifetime, I have come to the realization that what I was to learn from this problem was not the solution, but how much more science there is to do before we can give an answer. I am incredibly thankful for your code as it gave me a deeper understanding of the underlying algorithms! 
Best regards,